# Store view > Restrict or hide all clients groups display

Tags: magento-2.1

We have multiple stores/websites to manage in one Magento 2 instance.

We're creating a backend role for every store, and the problem is that when going to Clients > All clients we can see all the clients groups in filter.

[image]

Any idea of how to restrict it to only current website>clients or simply hide it ?